# How can I write this in a more convenient way?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

This question is part of a question deriving Fourier coefficients, so one of them is

$$b_n = \frac{1-\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})}{n\pi}$$

I think this is ugly, so

$$ b_n = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{2}{\pi n} & \text{n even and not multiple of }4\\
      \frac{1}{n\pi} & \text{n odd} \\
      0 & \text{ n a multiple of 4}
   \end{cases}$$

I want to write this as

$$b_n = \frac{1+(-1)^n}{n\pi} - \text{something}$$

where "something" is such that $b_n$ is zero when n is a multiple of 4

Comment: I know, but I could not think of a way to say it. :(

Comment: $b_n={1 \over n \pi}(1+ \operatorname{im} i^n)$. :-)

Comment: Jesus, that is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this looks any better but
$$b_n=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{n\pi}-\frac{2}{n\pi}\cdot\left\lfloor \frac{\lfloor n/4\rfloor}{n/4}\right\rfloor$$
works.